# validate the credit card expiry date using java?

Tags: java, regex, validation, date

I am looking to validate the credit card expiry date in MM/YY format . I have no clue on how to validate , whether to go for Simple date format / Regex .

Appreciate your help.

Comment: are you asking for a regex that will match MM/YY format, or are you asking if using a regex is a good idea in this case?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Playing devil's advocate...

```
boolean validateCardExpiryDate(String expiryDate) {
    return expiryDate.matches("(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])/[0-9]{2}");
}
```

which translates as:

- a non-capturing group ( [What is a non-capturing group? What does a question mark followed by a colon (?:) mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3512471/1143427) ) of: 0 followed by 1-9, **or** 1 followed by 0-2
- followed by "/"
- followed by 0-9, **twice**.

...so this version requires zero-padded months (01 - 12). Add a `?` after the first `0` to prevent this.

Comment: where are you checking if the date is in past or future , you just checking if this is valid number year and month

Comment: This is very true! Ah, but what century does 01/19 represent? :) The point is, at some point you're going to have to verify the card details are correct by actually using them against a payment provider. This is enough to verify that the expiry date is in the right *format* - that the customer has likely entered them correctly, that they'll fit in the appropriate database column etc. I would imagine that this would be sufficient for most needs.

Comment: For Kotlin you will need expiration.matches("(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])/[0-9]{2}".toRegex())

Answer (score 20):

Use `SimpleDateFormat` to parse a `Date`, then compare it with a new `Date`, which is "now":

```
String input = "11/12"; // for example
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/yy");
simpleDateFormat.setLenient(false);
Date expiry = simpleDateFormat.parse(input);
boolean expired = expiry.before(new Date());
```

#### Edited:

Thanks to `@ryanp` for the leniency aspect. The above code will now throw a `ParseException` if the input is not proper.

Comment: To be on the safe side, you'll want to explicitly set the time (eg. 00:00 ... etc) to avoid failing in the extreme cases

Comment: The problem with that is that "42701/13" will still validate if you don't use `SimpleDateFormat.setLenient(false)`, and "1/13" will also validate, which isn't what my card looks like!

Comment: It perfectly worked . I used the parse function but never uses setLenient(false) attribute so it was never workng

Comment: I have used the same code to check expiry but if we pass any year beyond 34 .e.g 01/35, 01/41 etc, the expired result is true. The parse method change "01/41" to 01/1941. Have you guys experienced this?

Comment: @amique The default cut over date is 1935, but you can set it to something else that works better for you: See [`SimpleDateFormat#get2DigitYearStart()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#get2DigitYearStart()) and [`SimpleDateFormat#set2DigitYearStart(Date)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#set2DigitYearStart(java.util.Date))

Answer (score 2):

### java.time

To validate whether you’ve got a valid expiration date string:

```
    DateTimeFormatter ccMonthFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/uu");
    String creditCardExpiryDateString = "11/21";
    try {
        YearMonth lastValidMonth = YearMonth.parse(creditCardExpiryDateString, ccMonthFormatter);
    } catch (DateTimeParseException dtpe) {
        System.out.println("Not a valid expiry date: " + creditCardExpiryDateString);
    }
```

To validate whether it denotes an expired credit card:

```
        if (YearMonth.now(ZoneId.systemDefault()).isAfter(lastValidMonth)) {
            System.out.println("Credit card has expired");
        }
```

Think about which time zone you want to use since the new month doesn’t begin at the same moment in all time zones. If you wanted UTC:

```
        if (YearMonth.now(ZoneOffset.UTC).isAfter(lastValidMonth)) {
```

If you wanted, for the sake of the example, Europe/Kiev time zone:

```
        if (YearMonth.now(ZoneId.of("Europe/Kiev")).isAfter(lastValidMonth)) {
```

**Link:** [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to use regex? Regex is really only suitable for matching characters, not dates. I think it would be far easier to just use simple date functions.

Comment: Yes , thanks . That is why i was confused and decided to ask the question .

Answer (score 0):

I think that code will be better:

```
int month = 11;
int year = 2012;

int totalMonth = (year * 12) + month;
totalMonth++; // next month needed
int nextMonth = totalMonth % 12;
int yearOfNextMonth = totalMonth / 12;

SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/yyyy");
simpleDateFormat.setLenient(false);
Date expiry = simpleDateFormat.parse(nextMonth + "/" + yearOfNextMonth);
boolean expired = expiry.before(new Date());
```

You need calculate next month because month displayed on credit card is the last month when card is valid.

Comment: In 2019 please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. At least not as the first option. And not without any reservation. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`.